# Intellij Idea live teamplate for create setters by class fields

Tags: java, intellij-idea, live-templates

Is it possible to (or alrady exists ) live template that when I have for example class :

```
public class Employee {
    private long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private double salary;
}
```

and i wrote:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {

        new Employee().set

    }
}
```

(line: **new Employee().set**)
and after pressing enter I will get something like this:

```
        Employee {writeYourVariableNameHere} = new Employee();

        {writeYourVariableNameHere}.setFirstName( {writeYourValueHere} );
        {writeYourVariableNameHere}.setId( {writeYourValueHere} );
        {writeYourVariableNameHere}.setLastName( {writeYourValueHere} );
        {writeYourVariableNameHere}.setSalary( {writeYourValueHere} );
```

I think this will be something nice to know how to do this because this sometimes save a lots of time.

---

I know shortcut ctrl + alt + V making this

```
Employee {writeYourVariableNameHere} = new Employee();
```

from this

```
new Employee()
```

or

```
new Employee().var
```

---

Do u know live template that will do this all for me?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such live template, because the code you're trying to generate does not make a lot of sense. It's much better to declare a constructor that will initialize all the fields (using the "Generate Constructor" feature) and then to pass all field values as constructor parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `generate` feature of Intellij Idea.

```
right click > generate
```

then you can select constructors for your variables and also the setters and getters.

Hope this helps.